# is it possible to upload test data file together with my post?

Tags: file

There is no choice to upload a test data file,although an image is OK.
The data file is just 2M. I just want to compare my result with other people.

Comment: This is a question about how stackoverflow works rather than about programming so it belongs on meta - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of people use [pastbin](http://pastebin.com) or other such services like [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com), [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com) and then post a link.